# How do you generate a certificate and key for VPN authentication

Tags: openssl, openssh, openvpn

We have a network of VPN routers another engineer had set up, I need to add a new one. Each router seems to have two files a .key file and a .crt file

I was left with a bunch of certificates and keys of the others routers and a CA.crt.

How do I generate a .key and .crt to authenticate my router and connect to this network.

One of the routers is server and has a key and crt called rvss.key and rvss.crt but also this ca.crt

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new Router/Client/Server to the existing network, you first should figure out where your [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Authority) is located at.
In your case it sounds like each router has/is his own CA, which contains only a .key file and a .crt file.
For each openvpn server/client you add, you will need to generate

1. a client/server .key (private, secret) on the client or server
2. a sign .req (request)

Now you copy the request to the CA and "sign" it. This will generate a client or server .crt (certificate) file. Copy the generated .crt along with the CA .crt back to the client/server.
The client/server will need a minimum of four things to work:

1. it's client/server key
2. it's signed .crt from above
3. the CA .crt
4. a proper configuration (ip/port stuff and more)

For "simple" step by step instructions I'd recommend this [Easy-RSA archwiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Easy-RSA) followed by this [Openvpn archwiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenVPN).
Please also note there are options to setup an [Advanced PKI](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/index.html), containing multiple sub-CA's, which your "vpn routers" could possibly become, depending on the use case. Anyhow, in this case each router then will also need the "root" CA certificate, which seems not to be the case at the moment.

Comment: That was a lot if help thanks. Turns out he was using his own laptop as the CA authority and hadn't sent me a CA.key. Once I got these I was able to generate new client certificate and key and was able to connect to the network.